# aws cli command on python 3.8 syntax error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, syntax, command-line-interface

I want to save the aws command in a variable.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import subprocess

aa = (subprocess.check_output(['aws ce get-cost-and-usage --time-period Start=2020-08-01,End=2020-08-31 --granularity=DAILY  --metrics BlendedCost |grep Amount | awk '{ gsub('\"',''); print $2 }' | sed 's/.$//''], shell=True)).decode('ascii').strip()

print(aa)
```

```
  File "test.py", line 5
    aa = (subprocess.check_output(['aws ce get-cost-and-usage --time-period Start=2020-08-01,End=2020-08-31 --granularity=DAILY  --metrics BlendedCost |grep Amount | awk '{ gsub('\"',''); print $2 }' | sed 's/.$//''], shell=True)).decode('ascii').strip()
                                                                                                                                                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What is the problem?

Comment: firstly, you're missing the ```)``` at the end of that line,  next, you need to escape those ```'```  i.e. ```\'```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the following form:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import subprocess

cmd = "aws ce get-cost-and-usage --time-period Start=2020-08-01,End=2020-08-31 --granularity=DAILY  --metrics BlendedCost --profile la |  grep Amount | awk '{ gsub(\"\\\"\",\"\"); print $2 }' |  sed 's/.$//'"

print(cmd)

aa = subprocess.check_output([cmd], shell=True).decode('ascii').strip()

print(aa)
```

The `print(cmd)` gives:

```
aws ce get-cost-and-usage --time-period Start=2020-08-01,End=2020-08-31 --granularity=DAILY  --metrics BlendedCost --profile la |  grep Amount | awk '{ gsub("\"",""); print $2 }' |  sed 's/.$//'
```

I can't confirm if the command actually works, but there is no syntax error at least.

Answer (score 2):

You have at least one problem in this expression:

```
'{ gsub('\"',''); print $2 }'
```

You have single-quoted strings inside single-quoted strings.  You have to escape the inner ones, or double them  Not that your doubled one serves only as a single.

```
'{ gsub(\'\"\',\'\'); print $2 }'

'{ gsub(''\"'',""); print $2 }'
```

Note that in the second one, I converted your empty string to double quotes; this saves one instance of escaping.